# How to check if an object has a custom property with python?

Tags: python, properties

The standard python `hasattr()` doesn't work for me, giving me `False` in every case:

```
hasattr(bpy.data.objects["object"], 'char')
```

How I can check for the existence of a custom property?

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two types of custom properties:

1. Properties global to a type, `bpy.props.*` for e.g. `bpy.types.Object`
   (`ob.char = "foobar"`)
2. ID properties local to a type instance
   (`ob["char"] = "foobar"`)

---

To test for bpy.props properties / attributes:

```
hasattr(ob, "char")
```

Or get the attribute:

```
# note: throws AttributeError if not existing
getattr(ob, "char") 

# don't throw exception but return default (None) value if not existing
getattr(ob, "char", None)
```

---

To test for a certain ID property, use:

```
bpy.data.objects['Object'].get('char') is not None
```

`get()` returns the value of the custom property assigned to the given key (the property name), or `None` if it couldn't find the key. You can make it return anything in case the key doesn't exist, like a string:

```
Object.get('char', default="Not found.")
```

Answer (score 8):

For custom properties, Blender mimics Python dictionaries *(which the following example applies to as well)*

To check if any datablock has property you can use Pythons `__contains__`

```
'char' in obj
```

Used in a script:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects["object"]
if 'char' in obj:
    print("has char")
```

You can also use `get` method, matching Pythons `dict.get`

```
value = obj.get('char', fallback)
if value is not fallback:
    print("char is:", value)
```